# Two files with the same name pointed by RUBYLIB?

Tags: ruby

I have two files with the same name "Foo.rb" in the directories pointed by my RUBYLIB env variable.

This causes the interpreter to fail, when 'require "Foo"' is invoked. It cannot know which to use.

How to solve this without renaming the files ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What happens if you explicitly specify the path to the file required?

Something like:

```
require 'lib/the/correct/Foo_folder/Foo'
```

Comment: Yes, I don't see any other alternative. Thx